# rails 3 app on linux (server old version of RoR installed)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new in deploying rails app on server and also in rails 3. I need your help.
I have developed a rails project in following versions.
Ruby 1.9.2
Rails 3.2.5 But where I'm deploying this project on Server, By default Rails 2.1.2 and Ruby 1.8.7 is installed. Is it the only way that I have to ask my service provider to install newer version because I have limited permission. 
If I install "bundler" gem and run bundle install will it work? As i mentioned rails version 3.2.5 gem 'rails', '3.2.5' in it too? (Apologize for a question may seem stupid? :-D )
What do you suggest? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer: **get another server**. There are cheap VPS available where you have full control over the environment so you can install whatever you want.

Trust me, **do not** depend on your service provider to do this for you. Your software will *always* be out-of-date, and you will be endlessly waiting for upgrades that never come. It's a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have gained full-access to server. Now its completely fresh. I have to do installation from scratch Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.2.5 Apache etc.
If you know any best article to follow instructions please let me know.
Thanks @shioyama

Comment: Great! I use Linode VPS and they have great documentation: http://library.linode.com/ I highly recommend it.